# JSF inserts <pre> tag automatically, disturbing the order on page

Tags: html, jsf, xhtml-transitional

I have a very basic JSF XHMTL page with the following content

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

<h:head>
<title>Pregled oglasa</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
<h:outputText value="#{oglasBean.naziv}" />
<br />
<br />
<h:outputText value="#{oglasBean.imeAutora}" />
<br />
<h:outputText value="#{oglasBean.prezimeAutora}" />
<br />

</h:body>
</html>
```

Here's the piece of code that sets up these variables:

```
public String pregledOglasa() {
    Map<String, String> reqMap = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
    int idOglasa = Integer.parseInt(reqMap.get("oglas_id"));

    for (Oglas oglas : aktivniOglasi) {
        if (oglas.getIdOglasa() == idOglasa) {
            this.setIdOglasa(idOglasa);
            this.setNaziv(oglas.getNaziv());
            this.setTekstOglasa(oglas.getTekstOglasa());
            this.setImeAutora(oglas.getImeAutora());
            this.setPrezimeAutora(oglas.getPrezimeAutora());
            this.setLokacijaDo(oglas.getLokacijaDo());
        }
    }

    return "/korisnik/pregledOglasa?faces-redirect=true";
}
```

What happens here is that "oglasBean.naziv", once when you open the page, comes after "oglasBean.imeAutora" and "oglasBean.prezimeAutora". Inspecting the code revealed that, for some reason, "oglasBean.naziv" is wrapped in **pre** tag and shows up the last, i.e. *after* "oglasBean.imeAutora" and "oglasBean.prezimeAutora":

[image]

In example given, "title 2" is meant to be *above* "John" and "Johnson".

Googling for this does't show anything similar, so it seems I am stuck here with a weird problem.

Even if I change "#{oglasBean.naziv}"

to "#{oglasBean.imeAutora}"

the problem remains the same, like JSF just takes whatever is first on the page and wrappes it in **pre**.

Comment: Your problem is not reproducible in an empty project with everything set to bare defaults and hardcoded data, so it's not a JSF problem.

Comment: Thanks, @BalusC. I seem to have solved it just by adding 'div' tag around everything. I posted solution as an answer. Thank you so much for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

OK, this one seems solved way quicker than I expected by experimenting with literally anything dumb I could have thought of. I tried wrapping everything in

```
<h:panelGroup layout="block">
```

to try to add **div** tag. It didn't work. Then I just tried plain **div** and voila, everything seems to be in order now, no extra tags or whatever:

[image]

I still wander if this is some kind of default JSF behaviour or maybe a glitch?

Comment: This is not default jsf behaviour. And the fact that there is whitespace on your 'source' html surrounded by " makes me think there is something special in your values.... So this is not a real solution mearly a 'workaround'

Comment: @Kukeltje Yes, I am also afraid this is just a workaround. Still, being short on time, I gotta stick to it at this moment. Will try to figure it out ASAP. Thanks for your insight!